# Converting Object Into an Array Based on Specific Key with PHP

Tags: php, arrays, magento, object

I'm quite new to PHP and I'm struggling converting an object into an array so that I can use that array in my code further down the line.

My script retrieves product data from the Magento API which shows as the following result after using `print_r` on the result variable:

[image]

Now I can see that this begins with "array" but when I try to use echo on the variable that I have assigned the result to, I receive the error `Catchable fatal error: Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string`.

How can I convert the object to an array and then split the array so that I have the values of all of the `sku` keys as an array as my eventual result?

I've tried using `array()` on the result variable and then attempted to manipulate it using array functions but no matter what I try I am receiving errors, so my thought is that I am not understanding this correctly.

Thank you for any insight that you can offer. My code is below if you need to see it:

```
<?php
    // Global variables.
    $client = new SoapClient('xxx'); // Magento API URL.
    $session_id = $client->login('xxx', 'xxx'); // API Username and API Key.

    // Filter where the 'FMA Stock' attribute is set to 'Yes'.
    $fma_stock_filter = array('complex_filter'=>
        array(
            array('key'=>'fma_stock', 'value'=>array('key' =>'eq', 'value' => 'Yes')),
        ),
    );

    // Assign the list of products to $zoey_product_list.
    $zoey_product_list = $client->catalogProductList($session_id, $fma_stock_filter);

    echo $zoey_product_list[0];
?>
```

Comment: You are receiving an array of objects (see the `stdClass Object`). So a simple type cast should work for your: `$array =  (array) $zoey_product_list[0];`

Comment: Thank you, this makes a lot more sense now :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you need is to rewrite all skus into an array, you can just do it like this:

```
$skus = [];
foreach ($items as $item) { // not sure which variable from your code contains print_r'd data, so assuming $items
    $skus[] = $item->sku;
}
```

A nice one-liner like this will also work:

```
$skus = array_map(function($item) { return $item->sku; }, $items);
```

But if you actually want to convert a standard object, or an array of those, a non-elegant yet working and simple solution is to convert it to JSON and back:

```
$array = json_decode(json_encode($objects), true);
```